# JavaScript function to transform a currency field in words

Tags: javascript

i found several scripts to do this with ENG/US currency, but I need it in Portuguese language, and its getting hard to find.

I've tried to modify a script to my needs but it is hard.

So, I found this script on web but it dont work too. What is wrong? `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier : lin23`

```
<script>
function number_format(a, b, c, d) {
    a = Math.round(a * Math.pow(10, b)) / Math.pow(10, b);
    e = a + '';
    f = e.split('.');
    if (!f[0]) {
        f[0] = '0';
    }
    if (!f[1]) {
        f[1] = '';
    }
    if (f[1].length < b) {
        g = f[1];
        for (i=f[1].length + 1; i <= b; i++) {
            g += '0';
        }
        f[1] = g;
    }
    if(d != '' && f[0].length > 3) {
        h = f[0];
        f[0] = '';
        for(j = 3; j < h.length; j+=3) {
            i = h.slice(h.length – j, h.length – j + 3);
            f[0] = d + i + f[0] + '';
        }
        j = h.substr(0, (h.length % 3 == 0) ? 3 : (h.length % 3));
        f[0] = j + f[0];
    }
    c = (b <= 0) ? '' : c;
    return f[0] + c + f[1];
}

function ValorPorExtenso(valor) {

if (!valor) return 'Zero';

var singular = ["centavo", "real", "mil", "milhão", "bilhão", "trilhão", "quatrilhão"];
var plural = ["centavos", "reais", "mil", "milhões", "bilhões", "trilhões", "quatrilhões"];

var c = ["", "cento", "duzentos", "trezentos", "quatrocentos", "quinhentos", "seiscentos", "setecentos", "oitocentos", "novecentos"];
var d = ["", "dez", "vinte", "trinta", "quarenta", "cinquenta", "sessenta", "setenta", "oitenta", "noventa"];
var d10 = ["dez", "onze", "doze", "treze", "quatorze", "quinze", "dezesseis", "dezesete", "dezoito", "dezenove"];
var u = ["", "um", "dois", "três", "quatro", "cinco", "seis", "sete", "oito", "nove"];

var z = 0;

valor = valor.toString();
valor = number_format(valor, 2, '.', '.');
alert(valor);
var inteiro = valor.split(/\./);

for (var i = 0; i < inteiro.length; i++) {
inteiro[i] = inteiro[i].toString();
for (var ii = inteiro[i].length; ii < 3; ii++) {
inteiro[i] = '0' + inteiro[i];
}
}

var fim = inteiro.length – ( inteiro[inteiro.length-1] > 0 ? 1 : 2 );

var rc, rd, ru;
var r, t;
var rt = '';
var valor_split;
for (var i = 0; i < inteiro.length; i++) {

valor = inteiro[i];
valor_split = valor.match(/./g);

rc = ((valor > 100) && (valor < 200)) ? 'cento' : c[valor_split[0]];
rd = (valor_split[1] < 2) ? '' : d[valor_split[1]];
ru = (valor > 0) ? ((valor_split[1] == 1) ? d10[valor_split[2]] : u[valor_split[2]]) : '';

r = rc + ((rc && (rd || ru)) ? ' e ' : '') + rd + ((rd && ru) ? ' e ' : '') + ru;
t = inteiro.length – 1 – i;

r = r + (r ? ' ' + (valor > 1 ? plural[t] : singular[t]) : '');
if (valor == '000') z++;
else if (z > 0) z–;

if ((t==1) && (z>0) && (inteiro[0] > 0)) {
r = r + ((z>1) ? ' de ' : '') + plural[t];
}
if (r) {
rt = rt + (((i > 0) && (i <= fim) && (inteiro[0] > 0) && (z < 1)) ? ( (i < fim) ? ', ' : ' e ') : ' ') + r;
}

}

return (rt ? rt : 'zero');

}

alert(ValorPorExtenso(8916165));
</script>
```

Comment: which line is the 23?

Comment: `i = h.slice(h.length – j, h.length – j + 3);`

Comment: You are doing the minifier's work yourself? Make your code readable, and leave to minifier whats minifier's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that you copied the code as is and pasted into a seperate file. There is a problem with the encoding of some characters. For example, so '-' are incorrectly encoded; so just replace them

```
i = h.slice(h.length – j, h.length – j + 3)
```

should be

```
i = h.slice(h.length - j, h.length – j + 3)
```

I know you can't see the difference, but the two characters are different.

Have a look at the modified code: http://jsfiddle.net/7P3Vy/

Comment: ah, I see now, you're rigth

Comment: i mean that he character '–' is not the same with - minus sign. I changed them for you.